# Python:Iterate over the list giving syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to execute my sql queries available in the below 3 variables. It's working fine when executing individually. For example:
`db_connection.execute(sales_updation)` is working.

```
kp_updates = ['sales_updation','price_updation','reward updation']

[db_connection.execute(i) for i in kp_updates]

Error: Syntax Error near sales_updation
```

Please suggest a fix.

Comment: Check your python version. It will execute fine in python3.0+ but will give Syntax Error in Python 2.7

Comment: @RichaBhuwania: i tried using for loop giving same error.. for i in kp_updates:
    db_connection.execute(kp_updates[i])

Comment: you should do `for i in kp_updates: db_connection.execute(i)`

Answer (score 1):

The above code should work in Python3.0+
Although if you have Python 2.7, then try executing in for loop.

```
kp_updates=['sales_updation','price_updation','reward updation']

for i in kp_updates: 
    db_connection.execute(i)
```